# Spring Cloud Config - Cannot clone or checkout repository

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am new using Spring Cloud Config.

I have this configuration:

### Config

**application.yml**

```
server: 
  port: ${PORT:8888}

spring:
  application:
    name: config-server 
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/username/SpringCloudConfig
          username: username
          password: password
          timeout: 4

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Class**

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I start the server at: http://localhost:8888/health

> {"status":"DOWN","diskSpace":{"status":"UP","total":494099492864,"free":440483053568,"threshold":10485760},"refreshScope":{"status":"UP"},"configServer":{"status":"DOWN","repository":{"application":"app","profiles":"default"},"error":"java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Cannot clone or checkout repository"}}

And i i try to start a Service it shows:

> 2018-08-08 13:43:38.270  INFO 32492 --- [           main]
>   c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server
>   at: http://localhost:8888 2018-08-08 13:43:42.884  WARN 32492 --- [
>   main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate
>   PropertySource:
>   {"timestamp":1533728622334,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server
>   Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","message":"Cannot
>   clone or checkout repository"path":"/producer-service/default"}"

### Service Config

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: producer-service
```

**Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProducerServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class Producer {
    @Value("${message}")
    private String message;

    @Value("${global-message}")
    private String globalMessage;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> message() {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();

        response.put("message", message);
        response.put("global-message", globalMessage);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an exception on the server?

Comment: {"status":"DOWN","diskSpace": > its a server health